# No events with a Combobox autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a `C#` code with a `combobox` and a working autocomplete code.
The problem is that when I choose a value of the list, there is no event that works like:

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

I have read already a lot but did not find a solution for the mentioned problem.
Maybe some of you guys know something?

Here is the autocomplete code :

```
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection combData = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        getData(combData);
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = combData;
```

At the moment it is a winform

Comment: Could you add enough of your autocomplete code so we can evaluate it?

Comment: Is the event wired up?

Comment: are you using `WinForms` or `WPF`?

Comment: i have add the code in the post , it is a Winforms at the moment

Comment: Did you try `comboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += 
   comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;`?

Comment: yes , i did this , with autocomplete code i doesn't work . it works when i add items manualy in the items collection

Comment: Have you thought about using the `TextChanged` event instead?

Comment: If the item isn't in the current list, it won't fire the index changed event, since the index hasn't changed.  That leaves you with the TextChanged event or the Validating events.

Comment: tnx for the tip , i uses first the textchanges , but after that i used the keypress event .    this.comboBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.comboBox1_KeyDown); when i choose the value and press enter , everything goes fine

Answer (score 0):

after a tip of using

```
comboBox1.TextChanged += comboBox1_textChanged;
```

i used the keypress event

```
this.comboBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(this.comboBox1_KeyDown);
```

with

```
private void comboBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {

                     label1.Text = comboBox1.Text;

            }

    }
```